# Anyone know why my .bash_profile is adding "export pyenv" everytime i open terminal?

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I had an issue where vscode was loading terminal in a blank screen and i got an error message in vscode saying "Unable to resolve your shell environment".

So i decided to check my `.bash_profile` file and was suprised to find it was over 700 lines where it was mainly just the following code repeated:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
```

I deleted the file and reopened terminal and realised everytime I open terminal, it adds the following lines:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
```

I installed pyenv straight forward following guides online so i'm not sure what time doing wrong.

If i delete `.bash_profile`  then reopen terminal, it recreates the `.bash_profile` and adds the following code.

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Note: I also have a `.zhrc` with the following exports which work as intended:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/

export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the other profiles that are loaded into the terminal, e.g. `.bashrc` and `.profile` (or `.zshrc` and `.zprofile` for zshell).

I had a similar issue where my `.bashrc` contained a script that would add the pyenv lines to another profile every time it was run.

Comment: yep I found my ```.zprofile``` had ```touch .bashprofile``` which was probably causing it to bug out.. thanks!